# Which version of MPI have additional features for developers

Tags: debugging, mpi, cluster-computing, distributed-computing

Currently I need to develop a program using MPI interface. There are several freely available MPI implementations and I wonder is there any which provides additional debugging tools, plugins for IDE etc.

Comment: Do you have a preferred platform? Linux? Windows? Mac? Which IDE are you using?

Comment: Linux + Emacs or Eclipse. Sometimes I do something on Windows + Visual Studio. In any case cluster uses Linux and I prefere to have similar to some extend enviroment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's not really how MPI works.   MPI profiling tools make use of a profiling interface that's built into the standard, and so ought to work with all MPI implementations.   Eclipse (for instance) has some MPI support in its Parallel Tools Platform, and that should work with all MPIs.